# Convert Array formatted as a string - Python

Tags: python, arrays, string, sockets, networking

I am receving a string through a socket like so

```
"['[0,0,0]','[0,0,0]']"
```

I would like to convert it back to a array. I have tried using

```
received.split(",")
```

however it splits up the arrays inside the array.

How would I go about converting the string to an array?

Comment: did you tried with `eval()` ?

Comment: What exactly do you want as the output? You already have a string...

Comment: sorry edited my question i meant array

Comment: I recommend using JSON and then using a JSON parser.  Keeps you away from eval, but gets you what you want.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan never eval data from the network.  Though the answer below seems to say there is a version of eval that is safe, as it cannot eval code.

Comment: @xaxxon Thanks! Can you see deleted post? I posted an answer very first after my comment then Mr. @[Tim](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1548678/tim) commented to my answer so I deleted I get your point.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan delete your comment suggesting it and I'll delete my comment saying what a bad suggestion it is.

Comment: @xaxxon No lets leave comments undeleted, our conversation is informatic  and related to question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = "['[0,0,0]','[0,0,0]']"
>>> s = ast.literal_eval(s)
>>> s
['[0,0,0]', '[0,0,0]']
>>> s = [ast.literal_eval(sub) for sub in s]
>>> s
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Using `literal_eval` is safer than `eval`. From the docs:

> #### [31.2. ast — Abstract Syntax Trees¶](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html)
>
> `ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)`
>
> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python expression. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python expressions 
>       from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values oneself.

Comment: Add documentation link: [31.2. ast — Abstract Syntax Trees¶](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) and link that suggests preference of your technique over simple `eval()` given by me: here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval.